# mvBacon from R to Python

Tags: r, python, outliers, numpy

I use package "robustX" in R in order to compute the Mahalanobis distance in a dataset to detect outliers, using more than one variable.

Specifically the code I am using is:

`Cb1 <- mvBACON(df[1:2],collect = 4, alpha=0.85, init.sel = c("Mahalanobis"))`

For timesaving issues, I want to start using Python instead. Is there a similar package or code I could use?

Comment: The first input of mvBACON should be a matrix (df[1:2] suggests a vector). Beyond that, mvBACON uses only simple functions (quantile of chi-2, Mahalanobis distances,...) so it is pretty straightforward to re-implement from scratch. I would be surprised you get any sizeable speed up by translating from R to python. Beware there are better alternatives to find multivariate outliers quickly [though](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/257269601_Shape_bias_of_robust_covariance_estimators_An_empirical_study).

Comment: Also, these are pseudo Mahalanobis distances you use, at any rate I would not call them Mahalanobis distance. This is because the distance used by mvBACON to flag the outliers lacks many of the characteristics of  Mahalanobis distances: it is for example not invariant to affine transformation of the variables.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the package or technique, but if you have some essential functionality in R that you cannot find/reproduce in Python without too much hassle, you can try using [rpy](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.4/html/index.html). I have never used it, but I came across it as the successor to [rmagic](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.4/html/interactive.html#module-rpy2.ipython.rmagic), which I believe allows the calling of R code within an interactive Python session or Jupyter Notebook, which, if you are not familiar with them, are pretty cool. You can always use it as a stop gap until you are able to implement your work in pure Python.

PS: If you are just getting started with scientific computing in python, I would recommend [Anaconda](https://anaconda.org/).